# Map as a function error for Flutter / OneSignal initState?

Tags: dictionary, parameters, dart, flutter, onesignal

I'm attempting to init my OneSignal package in flutter and getting a mapping error on my init parameters, specifically it's requiring me to run 'optional' iOS Settings and the settings aren't reading correctly. Here is my code...

```
await OneSignal.shared.init("OneSignal App ID", 
  iOSSettings: {
       OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
       OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: true
});
```

Here is the error I'm getting....

> [VERBOSE-2:dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception: NoSuchMethodError:
>   Attempted to use type 'Map' as a function. Since types do not define a
>   method 'call', this is not possible. Did you intend to call the Map
>   constructor and forget the 'new' operator? Receiver: Map Tried
>   calling: Map()

OneSignal.shared.init parameters are asking for `(String appID, {Map<OSiOSSettings, dynmic>, iOSSettings})`